# Circular statistics and bidirectional data

Tags: circular-statistics

I am curious if tests such as Rayleigh's test, Kuiper's test, and Watson's test are valid for bidirectional data (i.e. 180 degrees) as well as unidirectional data.
If not, what are the appropriate corresponding tests?

Comment: By "bidirectional data" do you mean data drawn from a bimodal distribution?

Comment: If there's only those two possible angles then there's no need for circular statistics at all.

Comment: Let me clarify - I'm testing for a bias in object orientation - objects have no top or bottom so 1 degree is exactly the same as 181 degrees.

Comment: You should be able to double the values of all your angles and use standard circular tests.

Comment: Thanks mimshot - so does that mean that if I were using data that were 0-90 degrees I would quadruple it?

Comment: Only if you considered 91 degrees to be the same as 1 degree (for example).